# table cells and rows are auto-resizing

Tags: css, resize, html-table

im building a minesweeper game, and i included a 10*10 table. i programmed it so that when a user clicks a "td", it displays either nothing, or a "b", or a number 1-4. however it also resizes (shrinks) when it does so, how do i prevent it from doing this?

css for table

```
table{
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0px;
border: 4px inset #444;
}
```

css for td

```
td {
margin: 0px;    
}
```

css before clicking

```
.box{
border: 3px outset #959595;
width:25px;
height: 25px;
}
```

this css is for a bomb ("b"), nothing, and numbers.(the difference with those is color)

```
.bomb{
border: 1px dotted #000000;
width:25px;
height: 25px;
}
```

[heres a link if that helps](http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mkeller/minesweeper.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the css after clicking?
i think it's resize because of border with diffrent value

Comment: oh yes didnt relize that thanx

Answer (score 1):

Use a developer's tool to very carefully measure out your box-models. You should be using some padding inside the `<td>` so that the borders do not overwrite or coincide with the table. My suggestion would be to use `display:block` on possible `<td>` contents and set the border so that it appears within the actual grid lines of the table.

Comment: can you suggest a tool?

Comment: What browser are you on?

Comment: firefox u mean something like firebug?

Comment: Yes, Firebug has a box model evaluation tool "Layout". They can come in very handy. I'm a Chrome guy myself and mine's called "Metrics".

Comment: @DevishOne do you know how i can have the browser accommodate the fact that some td's share a border (dotted) and some dont (outset) and still look normal?